# Show that any self-homotopy equivalence of $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ induces the identity homomorphism on $H^4(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z})$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I am currently working on the following problem:

> Show that any self-homotopy equivalence of $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ induces the identity homomorphism on $H^4(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z})$.

We recall here that $H^{\ast}(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ with $|\alpha| = 2$. That is, $\alpha$ is a generator of $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{C}P^{\infty} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ is a self-homotopy equivalence of $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$. Then, as a continuous map, $f$ induces a ring homomorphism $f^{\ast}:H^{\ast}(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^{\ast}(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z})$. Since $\alpha \smile \alpha$ is a generator of $H^4(\mathbb{C}P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, it will suffice to show that $f^{\ast}(\alpha \smile \alpha) = \alpha \smile \alpha$. Since $f^{\ast}$ is a ring homomorphism, we get $f^{\ast}(\alpha \smile \alpha) = f^{\ast}(\alpha) \smile f^{\ast}(\alpha)$.

To finish the problem, I just need to show that $f^{\ast}(\alpha) = \alpha$, but I'm not sure how to do this. I haven't yet used that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence -- could this help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the induced map $f^* : H^2(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z})$. Given that $\alpha$ is a generator of $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z})$, we have $f^*\alpha = k\alpha$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $f$ is a homotopy equivalence, $f^*$ is an isomorphism. What does this tell us about $k$?

Comment: Couldn't $k$ be $1$ or $-1$, representing the two possible isomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$? Could we easily rule out $k = -1$?

Comment: Exactly, $k = \pm 1$. We can't rule out $k = - 1$ because that possibility can occur. Regardless, what is $f^*\alpha^2$?

Comment: Aah, I see -- even if $f^{\ast}(\alpha) = -\alpha$ above, we get the desired equality $f^{\ast}(\alpha \smile \alpha) = f^{\ast}(\alpha) \smile f^{\ast}(\alpha)$. Thanks!